# I have created a neural network with 1 hidden layer and with parametric RelU as the activation for the hidden layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, relu

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import expit as sigmoid
from scipy.special import softmax as sm
import pandas as pd
import math
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from math import sqrt
from math import log

class NeuralNet:
    def __init__(self, num_features, num_hidden1 ,alpha,alpha1, max_epochs, num_output, _EPSILON):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_features=num_features  # number of input nodes (features)
        self.num_hidden1=num_hidden1  # number of hidden nodes for 1st hidden layer
        self.alpha=alpha  # learning rate
        self.alpha1=alpha1 # alpha for para RelU
        self.max_epochs=max_epochs # maximum number of epochs
        self.num_output=num_output # number of output nodes
        self._EPSILON=_EPSILON
        self.loss = [] #list to store losses per 100 epochs 
        self.trainingaccur=[] # list to store training accuracy per 100 epochs 
        self.devaccur=[]
        self.Weights_Input_to_H1=np.random.randn(self.num_hidden1, self.num_features)*(0.1)
        self.Bias_Input_to_H1=np.zeros([self.num_hidden1,1])
        self.Weights_H1_to_output=np.random.randn(self.num_output, self.num_hidden1)*(0.1)
        self.Bias_H1_to_output=np.zeros([self.num_output,1])
        self.dWeights_Input_to_H1=np.zeros([self.num_hidden1, self.num_features])
        self.dBias_Input_to_H1=np.zeros([self.num_hidden1,1])
        self.dWeights_H1_to_output=np.zeros([self.num_output, self.num_hidden1])
        self.dBias_H1_to_output=np.zeros([self.num_output,1])
        
        

        
    
    def relU(self,X):
        return np.maximum(X, 0)

    def Para_relU(self,alpha,X):
        return np.maximum(X,alpha*X)

    def Para_deriv_wrt_X(self,alpha,X):
        X[X>0]=1
        X[X<=0]=alpha

        return X
        

    def Para_deriv_wrt_alpha(self,alpha,X):
        return np.where(X<=0,alpha*X,0)

        
        

    def deriv(self,X):
        X[X>0]=1
        X[X<=0]=0
        
        return X
        
        


    
    def softmax(self,x):
        e=np.exp(x)
        for i in range(e.shape[1]):
            e[:,i]=e[:,i]/np.sum(e[:,i])
        return e

    
    

    
        
    # TODO: complete implementation for forward pass
    def forward(self, X):
        self.z1=np.dot((self.Weights_Input_to_H1),(X))+self.Bias_Input_to_H1
        self.a1=self.Para_relU(self.alpha1,self.z1)
        self.z2=np.dot((self.Weights_H1_to_output),(self.a1))+self.Bias_H1_to_output
        self.a2=self.softmax((self.z2))
        return self.a2
        
        
        
    
    # TODO: complete implementation for backpropagation
    # the following Numpy functions may be useful: np.dot, np.sum, np.tanh, numpy.ndarray.T
    def backprop(self, X, t):
      
        self.dz2=(self.a2.reshape(self.num_output,-1)-t.reshape(self.num_output,-1))/((self.num_output)*(X.shape[1]))
        self.dBias_H1_to_output=np.sum(self.dz2,axis=1,keepdims=True)
        self.dWeights_H1_to_output=np.dot((self.dz2),self.a1.T)
        self.dz1=(np.dot(self.Weights_H1_to_output.T,self.dz2)) * (self.Para_deriv_wrt_X(self.alpha1,self.z1))
        self.dalpha1=(np.dot(self.Weights_H1_to_output.T,self.dz2)) * (self.Para_deriv_wrt_alpha(self.alpha1,self.z1))
        self.dalpha1=np.sum(self.dalpha1)
        self.dBias_Input_to_H1=np.sum(self.dz1,axis=1,keepdims=True)
        self.dWeights_Input_to_H1=np.dot((self.dz1),X.T)
        
        
        
        
        
            
                
                
                
              
                        
                
      
        
        
    
    #TODO: complete implementation for fitting data, and change the existing code if needed
    def fit(self, x_train_data, y_train_data,x_dev_data,y_dev_data):
       
        
        
        for step in range(self.max_epochs):
            self.forward(x_train_data)
            self.backprop(x_train_data, y_train_data)
            self.Bias_H1_to_output=self.Bias_H1_to_output-((self.alpha)*(self.dBias_H1_to_output))
            self.Weights_H1_to_output=self.Weights_H1_to_output-((self.alpha)*(self.dWeights_H1_to_output))
            self.Bias_Input_to_H1=self.Bias_Input_to_H1-((self.alpha)*(self.dBias_Input_to_H1))
            self.Weights_Input_to_H1=self.Weights_Input_to_H1-((self.alpha)*(self.dWeights_Input_to_H1))
            self.alpha1=self.alpha1-((self.alpha)*(self.dalpha1))
            


            if step % 100 == 0:
                self.CCloss=log_loss(np.transpose(y_train_data),np.transpose(self.a2),eps=self._EPSILON,normalize=True)
                self.trainingaccuracy=accuracy_score(np.argmax(y_train_data,axis=0),np.argmax(self.forward(x_train_data),axis=0))
                self.devaccuracy=accuracy_score(np.argmax(y_dev_data,axis=0),np.argmax(self.forward(x_dev_data),axis=0))
                print(f'step: {step},  loss: {self.CCloss:3.150f}') 
                print(accuracy_score(np.argmax(y_train_data,axis=0),np.argmax(self.forward(x_train_data),axis=0)))
                print(accuracy_score(np.argmax(y_dev_data,axis=0),np.argmax(self.forward(x_dev_data),axis=0)))
                print(self.dalpha1)
                print(self.alpha1)
                self.loss.append(self.CCloss)
                self.trainingaccur.append(self.trainingaccuracy)
                self.devaccur.append(self.devaccuracy)
                
              
            
            
    def predict(self,X,y=None):
        self.forward(X)
        if(self.num_output>1):
            y_hat=np.argmax(self.a2, axis=0)
            temp=accuracy_score(y_hat,y)
        else:
            y_hat=np.where(self.a2>0.5,1,0)
            temp=accuracy_score(y_hat,y)
        return temp,y_hat
```

I tried to implement the gradient for the parameter of the parametric reLU which is dalpha1. However , not only is the value 0 when I print it out , I am getting a value very close to 0 when I tried to unit test the code by debugging using external cells.

I am not sure where the error is as when I checked the dimensions of each terms in the self.dalpha1 value everything is as according to expectations. Can someone suggest things that I may have overlooked so as to point me in the right direction?

I tried to replace the self.dalpha1 in the fit class with the entire np.sum expression, yet the alpha1 parameter is still not updated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that the parametric wrt x function also modifies the z1 array on passing it into the function.

By changing the function into using np.where , the z1 array is prevented from changing whilst still returning the correct array of parametric derivative wrt x.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import expit as sigmoid
from scipy.special import softmax as sm
import pandas as pd
import math
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from math import sqrt
from math import log

class NeuralNet:
    def __init__(self, num_features, num_hidden1 ,alpha,alpha1, max_epochs, num_output, _EPSILON):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_features=num_features  # number of input nodes (features)
        self.num_hidden1=num_hidden1  # number of hidden nodes for 1st hidden layer
        self.alpha=alpha  # learning rate
        self.alpha1=alpha1 # alpha for para RelU
        self.max_epochs=max_epochs # maximum number of epochs
        self.num_output=num_output # number of output nodes
        self._EPSILON=_EPSILON
        self.loss = [] #list to store losses per 100 epochs 
        self.trainingaccur=[] # list to store training accuracy per 100 epochs 
        self.devaccur=[]
        self.Weights_Input_to_H1=np.random.randn(self.num_hidden1, self.num_features)*(0.1)
        self.Bias_Input_to_H1=np.zeros([self.num_hidden1,1])
        self.Weights_H1_to_output=np.random.randn(self.num_output, self.num_hidden1)*(0.1)
        self.Bias_H1_to_output=np.zeros([self.num_output,1])
        self.dWeights_Input_to_H1=np.zeros([self.num_hidden1, self.num_features])
        self.dBias_Input_to_H1=np.zeros([self.num_hidden1,1])
        self.dWeights_H1_to_output=np.zeros([self.num_output, self.num_hidden1])
        self.dBias_H1_to_output=np.zeros([self.num_output,1])
        
        

        
    
    def relU(self,X):
        return np.maximum(X, 0)

    def Para_relU(self,alpha,X):
        return np.maximum(X,alpha*X)

    def Para_deriv_wrt_X(self,alpha,X):
        
        return np.where(X<=0,alpha,1)
        

    def Para_deriv_wrt_alpha(self,alpha,X):
        return np.where(X<=0,X,0)

        
        

    def deriv(self,X):
        return np.where(X<=0,0,1)
        
        
        


    
    def softmax(self,x):
        e=np.exp(x)
        for i in range(e.shape[1]):
            e[:,i]=e[:,i]/np.sum(e[:,i])
        return e

    
    

    
        
    # TODO: complete implementation for forward pass
    def forward(self, X):
        self.z1=np.dot((self.Weights_Input_to_H1),(X))+self.Bias_Input_to_H1
        self.a1=self.Para_relU(self.alpha1,self.z1)
        self.z2=np.dot((self.Weights_H1_to_output),(self.a1))+self.Bias_H1_to_output
        self.a2=self.softmax((self.z2))
        return self.a2
        
        
        
    
    # TODO: complete implementation for backpropagation
    # the following Numpy functions may be useful: np.dot, np.sum, np.tanh, numpy.ndarray.T
    def backprop(self, X, t):
      
        self.dz2=(self.a2.reshape(self.num_output,-1)-t.reshape(self.num_output,-1))/((self.num_output)*(X.shape[1]))
        self.dBias_H1_to_output=np.sum(self.dz2,axis=1,keepdims=True)
        self.dWeights_H1_to_output=np.dot((self.dz2),self.a1.T)
        self.dz1=(np.dot(self.Weights_H1_to_output.T,self.dz2)) * (self.Para_deriv_wrt_X(self.alpha1,self.z1))
        self.dalpha1=(np.dot(self.Weights_H1_to_output.T,self.dz2)) * (self.Para_deriv_wrt_alpha(self.alpha1,self.z1))
        self.dalpha1_scalar=np.sum(self.dalpha1)
        self.dBias_Input_to_H1=np.sum(self.dz1,axis=1,keepdims=True)
        self.dWeights_Input_to_H1=np.dot((self.dz1),X.T)
        
        
        
        
        
            
                
                
                
              
                        
                
      
        
        
    
    #TODO: complete implementation for fitting data, and change the existing code if needed
    def fit(self, x_train_data, y_train_data,x_dev_data,y_dev_data):
       
        
        
        for step in range(self.max_epochs):
            self.forward(x_train_data)
            self.backprop(x_train_data, y_train_data)
            self.Bias_H1_to_output=self.Bias_H1_to_output-((self.alpha)*(self.dBias_H1_to_output))
            self.Weights_H1_to_output=self.Weights_H1_to_output-((self.alpha)*(self.dWeights_H1_to_output))
            self.Bias_Input_to_H1=self.Bias_Input_to_H1-((self.alpha)*(self.dBias_Input_to_H1))
            self.Weights_Input_to_H1=self.Weights_Input_to_H1-((self.alpha)*(self.dWeights_Input_to_H1))
            self.alpha1=self.alpha1-((self.alpha)*(self.dalpha1_scalar))
            

            if step % 100 == 0:
                self.CCloss=log_loss(np.transpose(y_train_data),np.transpose(self.a2),eps=self._EPSILON,normalize=True)
                self.trainingaccuracy=accuracy_score(np.argmax(y_train_data,axis=0),np.argmax(self.forward(x_train_data),axis=0))
                self.devaccuracy=accuracy_score(np.argmax(y_dev_data,axis=0),np.argmax(self.forward(x_dev_data),axis=0))
                print(f'step: {step},  loss: {self.CCloss:3.150f}') 
                print(accuracy_score(np.argmax(y_train_data,axis=0),np.argmax(self.forward(x_train_data),axis=0)))
                print(accuracy_score(np.argmax(y_dev_data,axis=0),np.argmax(self.forward(x_dev_data),axis=0)))
                self.loss.append(self.CCloss)
                self.trainingaccur.append(self.trainingaccuracy)
                self.devaccur.append(self.devaccuracy)
                print(self.dalpha1)
                print(self.dalpha1_scalar)
                print(self.alpha1)


            


          
              
            
            
    def predict(self,X,y=None):
        self.forward(X)
        if(self.num_output>1):
            y_hat=np.argmax(self.a2, axis=0)
            temp=accuracy_score(y_hat,y)
        else:
            y_hat=np.where(self.a2>0.5,1,0)
            temp=accuracy_score(y_hat,y)
        return temp,y_hat
```